# How to modify the title metadata based on the directory name with FFMPEG?

Tags: windows, cmd, ffmpeg, filesystems, metadata

I have video files like: `C:\foo\bar.mkv`

But the metadata tags on the videos often reads like nonsense, like `blah blah blah foo blah blah bar 981237.mkv`

I'm pretty versed in using **FFMPEG** to re-encode with different codecs and such, but I would like to be able to edit the metadata to inherit the directory structure, so that the resultant file's metadata could take `C:\foo\bar.mkv` and change `title` metadata to: `Foo - Bar`.

Is there any method to do this with **FFMPEG**?

I'm aware that to manually modify metadata in **FFMPEG**, the command I'd need is `-metadata title="foo - bar"`.

The question is:

How do I retrieve the file and directory names for **FFMPEG** to use them for the `title` metadata tag?

Comment: Not directly, but it can be done with help from cmd, so this is one of those 2-in-1 questions. How to do this in ffmpeg? How to script this in cmd/batch? Basic command would be `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy -metadata title="Foo - Bar" outdir/output.mkv`. Now you just need the cmd/batch scripting part question to fill in the title contents.

Comment: Thanks @llogan - yeah, I'm familiar with the manual use of ```-metadata title="foo - bar"```. It's just the retrieval of the file and directory data I was needing help on. I'll edit my question to remove the confusion, though.

Comment: I wanted to make sure you used `-map 0` (map all streams) and `-c copy` (stream copy). Consider adding the [tag:batch-file] tag if using a `.bat` file is acceptable, and a new title such as "How to retrieve directory and file name in cmd" since this is more of a batch question than ffmpeg.

Comment: Please edit the question and include the code you are trying to make work. Are you wanting to do this change to every .mkv file on the drive?

Comment: @lit Let's assume all within a directory

Comment: Run in a command prompt window `for /R %I in (*.mkv) do @for %J in (%~dpI.) do @echo %~nxJ contains %~nxI` and you can see how to get name of the folder containing a file.